# Dynamically set OPENSHIFT_BUILD_REFERENCE and io.openshift.build.commit.ref in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

I have a relatively simple BuildConfig for a service.

```
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    app: identity-server
  name: identity-server
  namespace: dev
spec:
  failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  nodeSelector: {}
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'identity-server:latest'
  postCommit: {}
  resources: {}
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    git:
      ref: master
      uri: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7999/my-project/my-repo.git'
    sourceSecret:
      name: bitbucket
    type: Git
  strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
      dockerfilePath: Dockerfile.openshift
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: 'dotnet:2.1-sdk'
    type: Docker
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
    - imageChange:
      type: ImageChange
```

I can use it build an image from a tag in git like so.

```
$ oc start-build identity-server -n dev --commit 0.0.1
build "identity-server-22" started
```

This works well enough and the image is built from the commit as tagged.

However, in the last 2 steps of the build I see

```
Step 14/15 : ENV "OPENSHIFT_BUILD_NAME" "identity-server-25" "OPENSHIFT_BUILD_NAMESPACE" "dev" "OPENSHIFT_BUILD_SOURCE" "ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7999/my-project/my-repo.git" "OPENSHIFT_BUILD_REFERENCE" "master" "OPENSHIFT_BUILD_COMMIT" "6fa1c07b2e4f70bfff5ed1614907a1d00597fb51"
---> Running in 6d1e8a67976b
---> b7a869b8c133
Removing intermediate container 6d1e8a67976b
Step 15/15 : LABEL "io.openshift.build.name" "identity-server-25" "io.openshift.build.namespace" "dev" "io.openshift.build.commit.author" "Everett Toews \u003cEverett.Toews@example.com\u003e" "io.openshift.build.commit.date" "Sat Aug 4 16:46:48 2018 +1200" "io.openshift.build.commit.id" "6fa1c07b2e4f70bfff5ed1614907a1d00597fb51" "io.openshift.build.commit.ref" "master" "io.openshift.build.commit.message" "Try to build master branch" "io.openshift.build.source-location" "ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7999/my-project/my-repo.git"
---> Running in 3e8d8200f2cf
---> 1a591207a29f
Removing intermediate container 3e8d8200f2cf
```

`OPENSHIFT_BUILD_REFERENCE` and `io.openshift.build.commit.ref` are set to `master` as per `spec.source.git.ref` in the BuildConfig. I was hoping those would be set to `0.0.1` as overridden by the `--commit 0.0.1` flag in the `ōc start-build`.

Is there a way to dynamically set OPENSHIFT_BUILD_REFERENCE and io.openshift.build.commit.ref in OpenShift?

Or would I need to template the BuildConfig and replace the `spec.source.git.ref` with a parameter to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Tried to replicate, built with a commit sha (not a tag) and got these: `OPENSHIFT_BUILD_COMMIT=96490d85bb25f25f0a6006e6d8a991a52243fbb2
OPENSHIFT_BUILD_REFERENCE=96490d85bb25f25f0a6006e6d8a991a52243fbb2` which match the selected commit. Same for the `io.openshift.build.commit` annotations. Using minishift 3.9. What's yours?

Comment: One more thought - I used httpd i2s image, the behaviour may vary between base images. Which one did you use?